# setNeedsDisplayInRect redrawing entire view when using CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, tiles

this is my first time posting so please excuse any lapses in stackoverflow etiquette.

I haven't found any example code or any questions that address the problem I'm having, so hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

I'm using Quartz and I have a CATiledLayer on which I have drawn several boxes you can click on.  When you click one, I want to redraw that box with a blue outline, but not redraw the rest of the view.  From the comments I have read it seems like I should be using setNeedsDisplayInRect instead of setNeedsDisplay once I have clicked inside the bounds of one of the boxes, and set the dirty rect to the size of that box.  However, whenever my (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect function is called, the rect in (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect is always the size of my view, no matter what rect I tried to invalidate in setNeedsDisplayInRect.  I don't think I am calling setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect anywhere else, but for some reason the entire view is invalidated.  If I don't use a CATiledLayer, this problem doesn't appear and DrawRect receives the correct rect when setNeedsDisplayInRect is called.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>

#import "EAGLView.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"


// A class extension to declare private methods
@interface EAGLView ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) EAGLContext *context;

@end

@implementation EAGLView

+(Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //self.frame.size.width is 920
    //self.frame.size.height is 790
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        _myContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height, 8, 4*self.frame.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        _myLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(_myContext, self.frame.size, NULL);

        CATiledLayer *animLayer = (CATiledLayer *) self.layer;
        animLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 2;
        animLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);


    }
    return self;    
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code, rect is always equal to the size of the view (920,720)

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    testRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 100.0);
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:testRect];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Has anyone else run into a problem like this?  Is this a limitation of CATiledLayer or am I just using it incorrectly?  By the way, the reason I am using the CATiledLayer is solely so that I can maintain sharp graphics as I zoom in and out on a UIScrollView.  The CATiledLayer is embedded in a UIScrollView, but removing the CATiledLayer from the UIScrollView does not fix this problem.  If anyone can suggest a better alternative to get the "vectorized graphics" effect on zoom, please let me know.  I've spent a lot of time with CATiledLayer and I just can't get it to do what I want.

**Edit:  I can remove these lines and still get the same problem:**

```
CATiledLayer *animLayer = (CATiledLayer *) self.layer;
animLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 2;
animLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like if I add the line animLayer.levelsOfDetail = 2; right after animLayer.levelsOfDetailBias, it fixed the problem I had.  The correct rect is being sent to drawRect now, and there is no flicker as I update.  I guess that was a pretty simple fix, and I need to read up on how to use levelsofDetailBias and levelsOfDetail.

Edit:  This actually fixed another problem I had, but I still can't get the correct dirtyRect to be passed to DrawRect, so please disregard this

Comment: please add your edits as a comment or update your question, please do not post comments or updates as answers

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure I really understand what's happening.  Can anyone clarify this situation?

Comment: Madhup: Huh? This is the questioner's solution to the problem. A solution to the problem *should* be posted as an answer.

Comment: Rick: You've posted an answer on your own question. As far as I can tell, it answers the question, so there's nothing wrong with that. (Some people screw this up and address other answers or comments in non-answering answers.)

Comment: Sorry everyone, I posted this answer thinking I had answered my own question, but I was wrong, I still can't figure out how to get the drawRect to get the right dirtyRect.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm faced with a related problem for drawing CALayers -- wanting to update a small rectangle of a CALayer using **setNeedsDisplayInRect:** which isn't resulting in my delegate method **drawLayer:inContext:** getting called. Though it is called when I invoke **setNeedsDisplay** instead.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me too. Somehow, setting levelsOfDetail after the bias means that it won't redraw everything when you call setneedsdisplayinrect. Apple framework bug?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html): "the entire view will be redrawn if you call `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` or `-setNeedsDisplay:`."

It seems that the `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method doesn't give any benefits over the method `-setNeedsDisplay:`. This has lead to speculations that this behaviour is a bug in iOS's handling of redraws.

There doesn't seem to be a clean and simple solution. Among the suggestions are to break up your view into several subviews and request redraws only for those which are affected, or to keep track of the area to redraw on your own.

Some others, including me, had the same problem, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472500/ios-5-setneedsdisplayinrect-causes-a-fullscreen-invalidity) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776944/why-does-a-custom-child-view-of-a-uiscrollview-get-redrawn-entirely-and-not-only).